# Error in SQL-Oracle Code when raising value to the nth power - Need assistance

Tags: sql, oracle, exponent

I'm running SQL code within Oracle and need help revising the below "Update" script.  The below script gives me the error “missing equal sign” due to the " ^ " in the last line of the code that is meant to take the `Table-B.ValueY` value to the `Table-A.ValueZ` power.  I tried changing the last line to a Power (x,y) formula, but that gives me "%s: invalid identifier" error. I also went so far as to change the code completely into a CREATE TABLE, but that just appears be caught in a loop and never finishes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Original code:

```
UPDATE Table-A 
SET Column-X = 0 
WHERE 
  TABLE-A.mid = TABLE-B.mid AND 
  TABLE-A.tdlinx = TABLE-B.tdlinx AND 
  TABLE-B.ValueY ^ TABLE-A.ValueZ > 0.1;
```

Comment: The answer from @Randy is correct. You're getting the "missing equal sign" because one (very obscure) way to specify "not equal" in Oracle is `^=`, as in `WHERE value ^= 3`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a POWER function

```
SELECT POWER(10,2) FROM DUAL;
```

yours should look similar to this:

```
POWER( TABLE-B.ValueY, TABLE-A.ValueZ ) > 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but unfortunately I already tried the POWER function you outlined and receive the "%s: invalid identifier" error message associated with that line of the code.

Comment: do you reference table B anywhere in the real statement other than in the where clause?

Comment: i suggest replacing the POWER with a static number like 1, then you can concentrate on the rest of the syntax. when that works, replace the power part.

Comment: No, I don't reference table B elsewhere in my script aside from the WHERE Clause. I was able to get a Create Table to work with a revised POWER(X,Y) statement where I used the hard-keyed 3 as the exponent instead of a variable.  Just need to get it to work with the variable in question. Just a pain to take 3 steps vs. 1 since the UPDATE script won't work.